# Create responsive form with CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I am trying to build a resposive form with CSS flexbox.

I want the title of each input and the input itself to be on the same line.

I am trying to align the form so the inputs will be on the same vertical line, and the titles will align always to the right (See the code below)

In-order to do this, I put the titles and inputs and separate containers.

My problem is that because the the inputs are higher than the titles, after a few rows the form is no longer straight.

Do you know how it can be fixed? See the code below.

Thx! (:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
.parent
{
    border: 5px solid lightcoral;
    display: flex;

}


.child
{
    display: flex;

    text-align: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    max-width:300px;

}


.item{

    display: flex;
    margin:5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;

}
.item-input{

    margin:5px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .parent {
        justify-content:left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .parent {
        justify-content:center;
    }
}


</style>
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
<div class="item">Name</div>
<div class="item">Age</div>
<div class="item">Country</div>
<div class="item">Email</div>





</div>
<div class="child">
<div class="item-input"><input type=text></div>
<div class="item-input"><input type=text></div>
<div class="item-input"><input type=text></div>
<div class="item-input"><input type=text></div>




</div>
</div>

</div>
</htmL>
```

Comment: I would change you structure so that your labels are next to the inputs that way on smaller screens, you can stack the text above the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go :)
the span element has no effect, its just a way to give a text a class you want :p

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
.parent
{
    border: 5px solid lightcoral;
    text-align:center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;


}


.child
{
    display: flex;

    text-align: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    max-width:300px;
    align-content: right;

}


.item{

    display: flex;
    margin:5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;

}
.item-input{

    margin:5px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .parent {
        justify-content:left;
    }
}


</style>
<div class="parent">

<div class="child">

<div class="item-input"><span class="item">Name </span><input type=text></div>
<div class="item-input"><span class="item">Age </span><input type=text></div>
<div class="item-input"><span class="item">Country </span><input type=text></div>
<div class="item-input"><span class="item">Email </span><input type=text></div>

</div>
</div>


</htmL>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "aligning to the right".
But if you want to have the textboxes in the left column and the "labels" on the right, without changing the html, you can use `order`.

```css
.parent {
  border: 5px solid lightcoral;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  align-content: right;
}

.parent .child:first-child {
  order: 1; /*added*/
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin-left: auto;*/
}

.item-input {
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .parent {
    justify-content: flex-start; /*"left" is not recognized by Chrome*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item">Name</div>
    <div class="item">Age</div>
    <div class="item">Country</div>
    <div class="item">Email</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <div class="item-input">
      <input type=text>
    </div>
    <div class="item-input">
      <input type=text>
    </div>
    <div class="item-input">
      <input type=text>
    </div>
    <div class="item-input">
      <input type=text>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```